Positive operator is square of symmetric operator
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $B$ a bounded operator such that $\forall v\in H: \langle v, Bv\rangle\ge 0$. Is it true that there is a symmetric operator $A$, i.e., $\langle v, Aw\rangle = \langle Av, w\rangle$ for all $v, w$, such that $B=A^2$?

No. Every skew-symmetric operator on a real Hilbert space is a counter-example. For instance, $B = \pmatrix{ 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0}$.
If $B=-B^*$ and $B=A^2$, then $-B = B^* = (A^*)^2 = A^2 = B$.

Sorry, I should have been more specific. I was interested in the case where H is over C.

@shamwowexcitante In that case the proper terminology is not "symmetric operator" but "Hermitian operator" or "self-adjoint operator". Symmetric operators are usually understood as over $\mathbb{R}$.

@shamwowexcitante Regardless, the result is true over $\mathbb{C}$, and is an easy consequence of the spectral theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).
